# Unable to find IP of Localhost

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, localhost

i have windows machine running windows 8.1 and i have an asp.net site running on my localhost as i type localhost in web browser i get my site running there. but i want to access this website as ip address because i have to enable port forwarding in my router to access my site from another computer. i know that the address of localhost is 127.0.0.1 but when i type this address in web browser i got "HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.".
please help me in this as i am new to this

Comment: ok then? @PIMP_JUICE_IT

Comment: will u please tell me in which section i have to search for it?

Comment: wifi connection

Comment: actually i want to find my Localhost address only

Comment: second machine is not connected to my computer as i have to configure port forwarding on my router to access this machine through internet, so i just want to know when i type localhost in my web browser which ip address is fired up that loads website so that i configure that ip in port forwarding

Comment: no machines will connect to it through internet connection. it is not connected now but i will test this through my phone

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43169/discussion-between-waqas-ali-and-pimp-juice-it).

Comment: When you get 404 error, it means both: your network is ok (obvious since it's localhost) and web server is running and responding. Your web server / application is misconfigured though.

Comment: hey @PIMP_JUICE_IT i figured it out. i just removed the hostname from site bindings as it was 'localhost' and now i am browsing site either i type localhost or type 127.0.0.1

Comment: try **ipconfig /all | findstr "IPv4"**

Comment: ok then.?what to do next?